# How to Convert Float Keys to Integer Keys when Copying HashMap in Java?

Tags: java, hashmap, type-conversion

Hello Stack Overflow community,

I have encountered a challenge while working with Java's HashMaps. I have two HashMaps, map1 and map2, where map1 has keys of type Float and map2 has keys of type Integer. Now, I need to copy the entries from map1 to map2.

```
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class Q9 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<Float, String> map1 = new HashMap<>();
        Map<Integer, String> map2 = new HashMap<>();

        // Adding entries to map1
        map1.put(11.1f, "black");
        map1.put(12.1f, "brown");
        map1.put(13.1f, "Grey");
        map1.put(14.1f, "blue");

        // Now, I want to copy the entries from map1 to map2 with Integer keys
        // map2.putAll(map1); // This line gives a compilation error due to key type mismatch

        // How can I convert the Float keys from map1 to Integer keys to successfully copy entries to map2?

    }
}
```

I would appreciate guidance on how to convert the keys from Float to Integer so that I can successfully copy the entries from map1 to map2. Any insights, code examples, or best practices would be highly valuable.

Thank you for your assistance!

Comment: What do you expect to happen if map1 contains keys 10.1, 10.2, 10.9?

Comment: yeap it will only add one from it. But actually, I just want to know if it's possible or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Iterate the entries and cast the key value.

```java
for (Map.Entry<Float, String> entry : map1.entrySet()) {
    map2.put((int)(float)entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
}
```

We need to double-cast to trigger `float` auto-unboxing and `int` auto-boxing.

Alternative is it unbox directly to `int` manually, and let the compiler auto-box that.

```java
for (Map.Entry<Float, String> entry : map1.entrySet()) {
    map2.put(entry.getKey().intValue(), entry.getValue());
}
```

Warning: If two or more `float` values converts to the same `int` value, it is *arbitrary* which entry wins. That is the nature of `HashMap` ordering.

Answer (score 5):

You can iterate over `map1` and insert each entry to `map2` after changing the key to an `Integer`:

```
for(Map.Entry<Float, String> entry : map1.entrySet()) 
  map2.put(entry.getKey().intValue(), entry.getValue());
```